# single quotation break the program in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i compare words of RichTextBox  with database. but if i write word in richtextbox having single quotation then this program raise Exception.

**Example**
who resort to primitive and barbaric methods to kill 'Israeli's.
In this Sentence the Word **'Israeli's** having single quotation so this word break the program.
 i writes the following code.

```
private void btnSeparte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                    
                string MyConString = "server=localhost;" +
                "database=sentiwordnet;" + "password=zia;" +
                "User Id=root;";
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                string line = rtbEmotion.Text;
                Regex replacer = new Regex(@"\b(is|are|am|could|will|the|you|'|not|I|in)\b|(\b\d\b)");
                line = replacer.Replace(line, "");
                string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, " ");
                foreach (string part in parts)
                {

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from score where Word='" + part + "'", con);
                    con.Close();
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (r.Read())
                    {


                        txtBxPosEmot.Text = r["Pos"].ToString();
                        TxtBoxNeg.Text = r["Neg"].ToString();
                        pos = Convert.ToDouble(txtBxPosEmot.Text);
                        neg = Convert.ToDouble(TxtBoxNeg.Text);
                        listView1.Items.Add(part);
                        listView1.Items.Add(pos.ToString());
                        listView2.Items.Add(part);
                        listView2.Items.Add(neg.ToString());
                        pos1 = pos + pos1;
                        neg1 = neg + neg1;
                        r.Close();
                        con.Close();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                        txtbPosSyth.Text = "";
                        r.Close();
                        con.Close();
                    }
               }
          }
```

**Exception**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Israels'' at line

Comment: You can either encode the ' symbol on send and decode it, or replace it with another character (and replace it back when you read it). There may also be an escape sequence that's usable here.

Comment: Have you really just posted the root password of your server/database to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is classic SQL injection. In SQL, statements are encased in single quotes... So your single quote ends your statement prematurely since you're not escaping it. This also leaves you vulnerable to attack from malicious users. You must use parameterized SQL to avoid it. See: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 0):

In case you were wanting an explanation for the behavior that you're seeing, your regex isn't catching the `'` in your input because it has to be surrounded by a word boundary, which in your case, it's not.

the reason your regex breaks is because `'` causes a word boundary itself, so it has to be surrounded  by letters.

your regex doesn't account for this.

Comment: @ZiaRehman That depends.  what is your `replacer` actually for?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain has it occured to you that maybe the OP was trying to strip `'`s out of his input for reasons other that that it breaks the sql statement?  If that's the case then even if he uses Parameterized Sql, he'll still get incorrect behavior.

Comment: @SamIam: i want to remove the single quotation from word. so which regex i used.

Comment: @ZiaRehman your which single quotation did you intend to remove? and why?

Comment: @SamIam: because this break my program and i wants to replace  this single quotation with nothing

Comment: @SamIam: BCZ i need only Subjective Word

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31023/discussion-between-zia-rehman-and-sam-i-am)

Answer (score 0):

## Description

If you're looking to replace just the `'` trapped inside a word, then you could use the following regex.

```
(?<=\w\b)['](?=\b\w)
```

[image]

## Example

This php routine is included to simply show how the regex works.

```
<?php
$sourcestring="She said 'hi, this is Sam's house'. 
'The 'quick red f'ox jumpe'd over the 'laz'y brown dog.'";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\w\b)[\'](?=\b\w)/im','',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
She said 'hi, this is Sams house'. 
'The 'quick red fox jumped over the 'lazy brown dog.'
```